# pb to dlc conversion with snpe fails using a re trained Tensorflow Object Detection model

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection-api, qualcomm, snpe

Tensorflow version: 2.5

Snpe version: 1.51

Using a pre-trained model from the [Tensorflow Model Zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md), I am re-training it to detect only one class of object. Exporting the trained model as saved_model format according to TF2. However, running this through `snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc` cli command gives an error that the model is empty.

Command:

```
snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc --input_network ./models/mobilenet2/mobi/saved_model --input_dim input_tensor "1,320,320,3" --out_node detection_classes --out_node detection_boxes --out_node detection_scores --out_node num_detections --output_path mobilenet_ssd.dlc  --show_unconsumed_nodes --debug
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mouli/snpe-sdk/snpe-1.51.0.2663/bin/x86_64-linux-clang/snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/mouli/snpe-sdk/snpe-1.51.0.2663/bin/x86_64-linux-clang/snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc", line 67, in main
    raise e
  File "/home/mouli/snpe-sdk/snpe-1.51.0.2663/bin/x86_64-linux-clang/snpe-tensorflow-to-dlc", line 56, in main
    optimized_graph = optimizer.optimize(ir_graph)
  File "/home/mouli/snpe-sdk/snpe-1.51.0.2663/lib/python/qti/aisw/converters/common/converter_ir/op_graph_optimizations.py", line 189, in optimize
    remove_disconnected_nodes(graph)
  File "/home/mouli/snpe-sdk/snpe-1.51.0.2663/lib/python/qti/aisw/converters/common/converter_ir/op_graph_optimizations.py", line 406, in remove_disconnected_nodes
    raise ValueError("After pruning disconnected nodes, this model is empty.")
ValueError: After pruning disconnected nodes, this model is empty.
```

Warnings:

```
2021-07-20 13:00:46,640 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity with name detection_anchor_indices
2021-07-20 13:00:46,649 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_1 with name detection_boxes
2021-07-20 13:00:46,659 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_2 with name detection_classes
2021-07-20 13:00:46,669 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_3 with name detection_multiclass_scores
2021-07-20 13:00:46,679 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_4 with name detection_scores
2021-07-20 13:00:46,689 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_5 with name num_detections
2021-07-20 13:00:46,701 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_6 with name raw_detection_boxes
2021-07-20 13:00:46,714 - 188 - INFO - INFO_TF_CHANGE_NODE_NAME: Change node name: Identity_7 with name raw_detection_scores
2021-07-20 13:00:50,213 - 405 - WARNING - ERROR_TF_FALLBACK_TO_ONDEMAND_EVALUATION: Unable to resolve operation output shapes in single pass. Using on-demand evaluation!

2021-07-20 13:00:50,217 - 157 - DEBUG_1 - Added buffer named input_tensor:0 of shape [1, 320, 320, 3]
2021-07-20 13:01:31,590 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/TensorArrayV2_2) of type (TensorListReserve) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,590 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/StopGradient_1) of type (StopGradient) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,590 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/TensorArrayV2Stack/TensorListStack) of type (TensorListStack) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,591 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/while) of type (StatelessWhile) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,591 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/StopGradient_2) of type (StopGradient) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,591 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/TensorArrayV2Stack_1/TensorListStack) of type (TensorListStack) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,591 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/TensorArrayV2_1) of type (TensorListReserve) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,591 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_OP_NOT_SUPPORTED: Operation (StatefulPartitionedCall/map/TensorArrayUnstack/TensorListFromTensor) of type (TensorListFromTensor) is not supported by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/truediv_1) of type (ElementWiseDiv) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_6_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalClassHead_4/Reshape) of type (Reshape) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_16_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128_conv/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,595 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128_batchnorm/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_10_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_4_depthwise_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_13_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_7_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_4_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/convert_scores) of type (Sigmoid) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_6_expand/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128_conv/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_5_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_1_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_8_project/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Squeeze) of type (Reshape) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_add/add) of type (ElementWiseSum) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_7_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/scale_logits) of type (ElementWiseMul) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_5_depthwise_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,596 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_10_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_12_project/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_15_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalBoxHead_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalBoxHead_2/Reshape) of type (Reshape) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_12_add/add) of type (ElementWiseSum) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128_batchnorm/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_9_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_15_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_9_expand/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_expand_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_15_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_16_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_3_1x1_128/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_5_expand_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256_batchnorm/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_5_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_2_expand_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,597 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalBoxHead_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_1_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_4_1x1_128_batchnorm/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalBoxHead_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_2_expand/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_16_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_12_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_6_expand_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_4_3x3_s2_256/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_5_3x3_s2_128/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalClassHead_2/Reshape) of type (Reshape) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_13_expand/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_10_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/BoxPredictor/ConvolutionalClassHead_0/ClassPredictor/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_2_1x1_256/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_9_depthwise_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_9_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_11_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_3_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,598 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/Reshape_2) of type (Reshape) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/Decode/transpose_1) of type (SSDDecoderLayer) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_2_add/add) of type (ElementWiseSum) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_2_3x3_s2_512/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/expanded_conv_depthwise_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_8_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_7_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_11_project/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_4_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_11_add/add) of type (ElementWiseSum) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_2_Conv2d_3_3x3_s2_256/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_11_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_1_project_BN/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/FeatureMaps/layer_19_1_Conv2d_5_1x1_64_conv/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_project/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_14_expand/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_5_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,599 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/bn_Conv1/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_8_expand_relu/Relu6) of type (Relu6) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_9_project/Conv2D) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv_1_bn/FusedBatchNormV3) of type (BatchNormalization) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_15_add/add) of type (ElementWiseSum) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/Postprocessor/stack_1) of type (Pack) is not consumed by converter.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,600 - 193 - WARNING - WARNING_TF_LAYER_NOT_CONSUMED: Layer (StatefulPartitionedCall/ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/block_10_depthwise/depthwise) of type (Convolution) is not consumed by converter.

 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
2021-07-20 13:01:31,615 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Applying graph Optimizations...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,616 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['constant', 'elementwise_product', 'constant', 'elementwise_sum']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,616 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,616 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['pad']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,617 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,617 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['concatenation']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,617 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,617 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['concatenation']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,618 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,618 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['reshape', 'permute', 'reshape']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,618 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,618 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum', 'neuron', 'elementwise_product', 'elementwise_product']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum', 'neuron', 'elementwise_product', 'elementwise_product']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum', 'neuron', 'elementwise_product', 'elementwise_div']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,619 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum', 'neuron', 'elementwise_div', 'elementwise_product']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,620 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,620 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['reshape', 'permute', 'reshape', 'permute', 'reshape', 'permute', 'reshape']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,620 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,620 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['scale']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,621 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,621 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_product']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,621 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,621 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_div']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,622 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,622 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,622 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,622 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sub']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,622 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,623 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['convolution']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,623 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,623 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['fully_connected']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,623 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,623 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['non_max_suppression']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Evaluating to match Sequence ['elementwise_sum']...
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 164 - DEBUG_2 - Found 0 match(es)
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 193 - WARNING - Output node detection_classes, specified via command line, does not exist in graph.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 193 - WARNING - Output node detection_boxes, specified via command line, does not exist in graph.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 193 - WARNING - Output node detection_scores, specified via command line, does not exist in graph.
2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 193 - WARNING - Output node num_detections, specified via command line, does not exist in graph.

2021-07-20 13:01:31,624 - 183 - ERROR - Conversion FAILED!
```

**NOTE**: Running the same command on the pre-trained model directly results in the successful conversion of the model.

I am assuming the error is due to the change in the number of classes while re-training the model. What can be done to solve this error? There is minimal information out there regarding this and the Qualcomm Developer forum seems to be completely inactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Found the problem to be in the internal script of the object detection API, can be solved by using older commit versions of `exporter_main_v2.py` and `exporter_lib_v2.py`

To anyone having the same issue, refer to this Github thread,
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10120

Specifically this comment
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/10120#issuecomment-881984975